# Join domain for customer's PC throught ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, join, dns

For now code below in my tool work perfectly. When our customer run tool, click JOIN button, tool will call web service to get PASSWORD for variable __jdPass. The problem are about security, if customer disassembly (e.g dnSpy), run debugging, they can see the PASSWORD. I know the  .NET Obfuscator, but not sure about this.
So can I join domain for customer's PC throught ASP .NET ? Can I use dlls "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" or "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols" to accomplish via web service ?

```
using (ManagementObject wmiObject = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" + Environment.MachineName + "'")))
{
    using (ManagementBaseObject inParams = wmiObject.GetMethodParameters("JoinDomainOrWorkgroup"))
    {
        inParams["Name"] = _domainFull;
        inParams["UserName"] = __jdUser;
        inParams["Password"] = __jdPass;
        inParams["FJoinOptions"] = 3;
        using (ManagementBaseObject joinParams = wmiObject.InvokeMethod("JoinDomainOrWorkgroup", inParams, null))
        {
            state.Value = joinParams["ReturnValue"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for something [like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/593152/adding-remote-machine-to-ad-via-powershell)? it appears you can reverse the process and have your server log into client machines and add the remotely

Comment: Thank @timur, join domain via remoting powershell are fine, but customer don't like enter shell script (e.g enable remoting ps), they will may be fix the problem firewall... And more, we have some convention PC name need to check and return from web service.